# Hidden Custom option Magento

Tags: magento

I'm looking for the file name containing the implementation of the "Proceed to Checkout" button.

I have found that the `sales_flat_quote_item` table is being populated when the button is clicked.  I have added a field called `fld_data` and now I need to insert the field data, currently held in a session, when the "Proceed to Checkout" button is clicked, in the same insert statement.

---

Sorry for the misunderstanding actually i want to add a custom option textfield which is hidden from the user and process it till the order submitted and that value is accessable at the admin side along with the order.

Comment: wat? Please explain in english :) what you are trying to do and what you already have tried to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Khaleel if I read your name correctly... you should get the template at

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage
```

and the layout for the template at:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml
```

and the block at:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Link.php
```

Make sure you overwrite none of these core files but have a local version.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting or copying core files to the local folder isn't necessary here (if the additional data is related to the product)

Just create a custom module and in the mysql setup file, add a custom column to the required tables to hold your attribute value:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'), 'your_attribute', "decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `price`");
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order_item'), 'your_attribute', "decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `price`");
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/invoice_item'), 'your_attribute', "decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `price`");
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/shipment_item'), 'your_attribute', "decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `price`");
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/creditmemo_item'), 'your_attribute', "decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `price`");
```

Then, in your custom modules config.xml file, inside the global tag, place the following

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <your_attribute><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></your_attribute>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <your_attribute>
            <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
            <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
            <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
        </your_attribute>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>

<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <your_attribute/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

this should do the trick without modifying core code.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? Perhaps provide a structured view of how the extension would look? I can't seem to get it to "activate" and add the tables. Thank you!